# Theme issues in Magento 2

Tags: magento

I have created the new theme with folder structure as give in the document . I have setup the new theme in the admin panel also .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGoy5.png)

The problem is new theme is coming in the front-end but once i copy the module like search from vendor to the new theme but in the front-end still coming from the vendor .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyq1X.png)

How to over come this any help me in this plzz..

Answer (score 0):

Like you need frontend files should come from your theme not from vendor. Then you have to do like this:

For magento-search module

1. Create a folder under your theme "Magento_Search".
2. Copy templates folder from vender/module-search/view/frontend/ and put under "Magento_Search" folder .
3. Now view files will comes from your theme search folder. You can do it same for layout and web also.